# How can I execute a .bat file as Administrator on startup?

Tags: command-line, windows-8

We want to autorun `d:\func.bat` when we log in to Windows 8.

We have added `test.cmd` to `C:\Users\<User Profile>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. When we reboot or start Windows 8 and auto run `d:\func.bat`, but we found some tools as administrator.

I want to auto run Command Prompt as Administrator and run `d:\func.bat` result ok.

Answer (score 12):

Try using **Task Scheduler** to run the desired batch or cmd file at startup.

The difference with **Task Scheduler** is that you can provide credentials with which the application should run(Administrator in your case).

Comment: i have tried out this way, but it cannot work.could you support to detail information？thanks

Comment: Don't forget that you have to start the batch file via `cmd.exe /c test.cmd`

Answer (score 1):

Put this at the top of your bat file. Thanks to who ever figured this out. not my code. Tested on Windows 10 x64

```
@echo off
:: BatchGotAdmin (Run as Admin code starts)
REM --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )
:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B
:gotAdmin
if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
:: BatchGotAdmin (Run as Admin code ends)
:: Your codes should start from the following line
```

Comment: Do you not have a source at all?

Comment: The source appears to be https://sites.google.com/site/eneerge/scripts/batchgotadmin . This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding CMD Run as Administrator

What I do is right click the program or its shortcut: Properties, seek an Advanced button, tick - Run as Administrator.

Click OK, then OK the next menu.

Comment: I want to let the machine auto run this batch file when login Windows 8 OS

Comment: Hello me. Anyway, You could turn of UAC, but that might not be very safe. I think Task Scheduler would be the best way as tumchaaditya said.